# OpenCV with Ruby error

Tags: ruby, macos, opencv, homebrew, libpng

I am using the `ruby-opencv` gem to work with opencv on ruby. I used Homebrew for installing opencv. installation of opencv and ruby were successful, but I get the following error when I try running any example -

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0/ruby-opencv-0.0.14/opencv.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib requires version 34.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 33.0.0 - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0/ruby-opencv-0.0.14/opencv.bundle
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby-opencv-0.0.14/lib/opencv.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
    from opencv.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

What do I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in error message (here: `requires version 34.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 33.0.0`) OpenCV requires libpng in version 34.00 or later (and you have 33.0.0), so you need to install newer version of this lib. If simple `brew install libpng` will not solve the problem try to uninstall it and than use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23100464/1598485) to install it again.